# How can I remove lines of a file that don't contain a number?

Tags: python

I have a file containing lines that look like this:

```
43
763
hello
4903
world

2632
hello 382
```

I need to strip every line which doesn't contain a number. That means the line can stay if it contains a string but only if it also contains any number.

The output would be:

```
43
763
4903
2632
hello 382
```

edit:
So now I've got

```
with open('numstest.txt') as oldfile, open('numtest2.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not line.isalpha():
            newfile.write(line)
```

But for some reason, it's outputting the file exactly the same.

Comment: I would go with a regex, like if you find \d then you know there is a digit so print line. Are your characters plain english?

Comment: then it should do the trick. look at re module, it should give you something to start with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a regular expression as follows

```
s = """43
       763
       hello
       4903
       world

       2632
       hello 382"""

p = re.compile(r"\d")
lines = (line for line in s.splitlines() if p.search(line))
for line in lines:
    print(line)
43
763
4903
2632
hello 382
```

See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your strings to a list and print only the correct strings using the `isalpha()` method.

```
ls = ["43","763","hello","4903","world","2632","hello 382"]
for i in ls:
    if not i.isalpha():
        print(i)
```

**EDIT**: To get the file IO right, strip the newline character from a line before you check, so something like this:

```
with open('numstest.txt') as oldfile, open('numtest2.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not line.strip().isalpha():
            newfile.write(line)
```

The `strip` method removes the whitespace characters from both ends of a string so that you get the string `"hello"` for example, instead of `"hello\n"`

Comment: `file.readlines()` or `for line in file` will give him list :)

Comment: Doesn't really work, it accepts a lot of false positives (e.g. `"abc$"`)

Comment: @VincentSavard, He doesn't mention which symbols can occur in his case

Comment: @VincentSavard try `"hello ".isalpha()`. It will give `False`. You might have to `strip`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about isalpha(). Please look at my edited question. I still cannot get it working for some reason.

Comment: @Leva7 The question literally is "How can I remove lines of a file that don't contain a number?". Your post does not answer this question. It just happens that the example provided by the OP works with your code, but it doesn't make it right.

Comment: @CPanda You may have intended to ping Leva7, not me.

Comment: @VincentSavard Yeah..sorry